# Derivatives on interval: positivity of second derivative to the left

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose on the interval $[-a,a]$, we have a strictly decreasing function $f$ with $f'(-a)=f'(a)$ and, say, $f(-a)=1, f(a)=0$.

Suppose there exists some $x_0\in [-a,a]$ such that $f'(x_0)<-M$ for some $M>0$, implies $f''(x_0)>0$.

Is it true that then $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in [-a,x_0]$, which means that $f'(x)$ increases on $[-a,x_0]$?

Comment: $f'(-a)=f'(a)$ and $f(-a)=1,f(a)=0$ can't be both true.